# Set pseudo element height through jQuery

Tags: jquery, height, pseudo-element

I am trying to set a pseudo element relative to another div, but as I have noticed, it's not possible to set it directly so I tried to add it in a  element in head, but you can't use variable if you do it, which I need.

Here is my code.

```
var sectionHeight = 0;
        $(window).load(function(){
            sectionHeight = $('.checkheight').outerHeight(true);
            $("#section1::before").css({"height":sectionHeight});


        })
```

That is what I first had, before I knew  I couldn't set pseudo elements' attributes in css through jquery

this is what I have now

```
var sectionHeight = 0;
        $(window).load(function(){
            sectionHeight = $('.checkheight').outerHeight(true);


        })
        $('<style>#section1:before{height: sectionHeight }</style>').appendTo('head');
```

but it won't use the variable to set the height.

Would anyone know a proper solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to append the style tag inside the `onload` handler

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var sectionHeight = $('.checkheight').outerHeight(true);

    $('<style>#section1:before {height: ' + sectionHeight + 'px;}</style>').appendTo('head');
});
```

Comment: It did at the <style></style> element but it will set the height to "sectionHeight", as you can see in this screenshot: http://imgur.com/GofDyGO

Comment: @user3808051 - Oh, didn't notice that, edited the answer

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this but without the <style> getting written each time the function is called? I have a situation where I call the function on page resize to change a value based on the new page size... I get loads of inline <style>'s added in the <head> which is messy...? I could bin them all on the start of each function and then just write the new one i guess? that possible?